# how to call rating view from json and show the rating in my table view

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, uitableview

I have one custom cell, in that i have " name", "address" "rating view". Rating view is one class separately library file for rating view it will have some 3 images ( full star, half star, empty star ). Now from my json data i have some rating values for each cell. like below json structure :

This is my custom cell :

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var vendorName: UILabel!   // vendor label name

    @IBOutlet weak var vendorAddress: UILabel!   // vendor address aname

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
```

My table view controller :

i have 2 more custom cell.But if i try to add for one cell i will make and understand code and i will do for all custom cell.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            // if cell tap condition

        if(isTapped == true && indexPath == selectedIndex)
        {



            if (premiumUserCheck && indexPath == selectedIndex ) {

                let cell1:premiumUsercell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! premiumUsercell

                cell1.phoneNumber = (arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("phone") as? String)!
                cell1.vendorName3.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name") as? String
                cell1.vendorAdddress3.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address") as? String

                print("premium user")

                return cell1


            }
            else {

                let cell1:ExpandCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! ExpandCell


                cell1.VendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name") as? String
                cell1.vendorAdress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address") as? String
                //cell1.externalView.hidden = true

                print("non premium user") 
                return cell1 
            } 
        } 



        // show default cutsom cell

        let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell 


        cell.vendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name") as? String 
        cell.vendorAddress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address") as? String 

        print("norml user") 



        return cell 
    }
```

Here below code is rating view is some library files , which i am using for rating view. i place custom view under one view inside my custom cell.I have to select my view in my custom cell. And i have to assign that particular class as `RatingView` classes..Then if i click my rating view in my custom cell , i can see like below image to set `rating star, number of star, off, empty half image:

[image]

My `ratingviewclasses`:

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol RatingViewDelegate {
    /**
     Called when user's touch ends

     - parameter ratingView: Rating view, which calls this method
     - parameter didChangeRating newRating: New rating
    */
    func ratingView(ratingView: RatingView, didChangeRating newRating: Float)
}

/**
 Rating bar, fully customisable from Interface builder
*/
@IBDesignable
public class RatingView: UIView {

    /// Total number of stars
    @IBInspectable public var starCount: Int = 5

    /// Image of unlit star, if nil "starryStars_off" is used
    @IBInspectable public var offImage: UIImage?

    /// Image of fully lit star, if nil "starryStars_on" is used
    @IBInspectable public var onImage: UIImage?

    /// Image of half-lit star, if nil "starryStars_half" is used
    @IBInspectable public var halfImage: UIImage?

    /// Current rating, updates star images after setting
    @IBInspectable public var rating: Float = Float(0) {
        didSet {
            // If rating is more than starCount simply set it to starCount
            rating = min(Float(starCount), rating)

            updateRating()
        }
    }

    /// If set to "false" only full stars will be lit
    @IBInspectable public var halfStarsAllowed: Bool = true

    /// If set to "false" user will not be able to edit the rating
    @IBInspectable public var editable: Bool = true


    /// Delegate, must confrom to *RatingViewDelegate* protocol
    public weak var delegate: RatingViewDelegate?

    var stars = [UIImageView]()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        customInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        customInit()
    }

    override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        customInit()
    }


    func customInit() {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: RatingView.self)

        if offImage == nil {
            offImage = UIImage(named: "star_empty", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
        }
        if onImage == nil {
            onImage = UIImage(named: "star_full", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
        }
        if halfImage == nil {
            halfImage = UIImage(named: "star_half_full", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: self.traitCollection)
        }

        guard let offImage = offImage else {
            assert(false, "offImage is not set")
            return
        }

        for var i = 1; i <= starCount; i++ {
            let iv = UIImageView(image: offImage)
            addSubview(iv)
            stars.append(iv)

        }

        layoutStars()
        updateRating()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layoutStars()
    }

    func layoutStars() {
        if stars.count != 0,
            let offImage = stars.first?.image {
                let halfWidth = offImage.size.width/2
                let distance = (bounds.size.width - (offImage.size.width * CGFloat(starCount))) / CGFloat(starCount + 1) + halfWidth

                var i = 1
                for iv in stars {
                    iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, offImage.size.width, offImage.size.height)

                    iv.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * distance + halfWidth * CGFloat(i - 1),
                        self.frame.size.height/2)
                    i++
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     Compute and adjust rating when user touches begin/move/end
    */
    func handleTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)

        for var i = starCount - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            let imageView = stars[i]

            let x = touchLocation.x;

            if x >= imageView.center.x {
                rating = Float(i) + 1
                return
            } else if x >= CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame) && halfStarsAllowed {
                rating = Float(i) + 0.5
                return
            }
        }

        rating = 0
    }

    /**
     Adjust images on image views to represent new rating
     */
    func updateRating() {
        // To avoid crash when using IB
        if stars.count == 0 {
            return
        }

        // Set every full star
        var i = 1
        for ; i <= Int(rating); i++ {
            let star = stars[i-1]
            star.image = onImage
        }

        if i > starCount {
            return
        }

        // Now add a half star
        if rating - Float(i) + 1 >= 0.5 {
            let star = stars[i-1]
            star.image = halfImage
            i++
        }


        for ; i <= starCount; i++ {
            let star = stars[i-1]
            star.image = offImage
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Override UIResponder methods

extension RatingView {
    override public func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard editable else { return }
        handleTouches(touches)
    }

    override public func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard editable else { return }
        handleTouches(touches)
    }

    override public func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard editable else { return }
        handleTouches(touches)
        guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
        delegate.ratingView(self, didChangeRating: rating)
    }
}
```

Now i need to get the rating number from my json and i have to assign to my uiview in my custom cell, and i need to show the respective rating in my all table view cell.

Please help me out. I am strugling to do with getting json data dynamically??

Thnaks !

UPDATED :

```
customcell.swift

  @IBOutlet weak var ratingView: RatingView!


    @IBOutlet weak var vendorName: UILabel!   // vendor label name

    @IBOutlet weak var vendorAddress: UILabel!   // vendor address aname

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        super.awakeFromNib()
        //ratingView = RatingView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, cellHeight))
        // Initialization code
    }
```

Viewcontroller.swift

```
let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell 

            let ratingString = "\(arrDict[indexPath.section].valueForKey("rating"))"
            cell.ratingView?.rating = Float(ratingString)!

        cell.vendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name") as? String 
        cell.vendorAddress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address") as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `RatingView` as a subview in `TableViewCell`'s `awakeNib` method and make it as global variable say `ratingView`. then

```
var ratingView:RatingView? = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    ratingView = RatingView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, cellHeight)) // your requiredFrame
}
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let ratingString = "\(arrDict[indexPath.section].valueForKey("rating"))"
if let ratingValue = Float(ratingString) {
   cell1.ratingView?.rating = ratingValue
}
else {
   cell1.ratingView?.rating = 0
}
```

Comment: in my custom cell i need to set the rating view as subview of table view cell??.... can you post some same code of how my custom cell awakeNib method to be??

Comment: i am getting error in my cell row at index path that ` Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'``

Comment: And in that `awakefromnib` why you setting frame??, because i already set the view and added constraints and i have set the name as `RatingView` as iboutlet to my customcell

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var ratingView: RatingView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    super.awakeFromNib()
    ratingView = RatingView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, cellHeight))
    // Initialization code
}
`

Comment: you are connecting ratingView in xib file right? then why you need to alloc it again?

Comment: first i did iboutlet of my rating view to my xib and i named as `ratingView`....now. in this line `var ratingView:RatingView? = nil
` and ` ratingView = RatingView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidth, cellHeight))` which i have to assign as my iboutlet `ratingView`

Comment: And i haven't set cellwidth,cell hight??

Comment: i have one uiview and i mentioned the class as Rating view.. And  i did iboutlet to my customcell.xib and that is ` @IBOutlet weak var ratingView: RatingView!`... Now in my custom cell code what i have to update as per your answer code

Comment: again app getting crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: check my post please

Comment: why there is 2 super.awakeFromNib() ?

Comment: i delete that !... but still i am getting crash under my cell row at index path on that code `let ratingString = "\(arrDict[indexPath.section].valueForKey("rating"))"
cell1.ratingView?.rating = Float(ratingString)`

Comment: what is the crash you are getting?

Comment: i am suggesting you to learn something about the basics of swift.

Comment: in your code , whats that  `Float(str)`,  haven't declare anything for `str`

Comment: stars are showing but its all empty, based on my rating number its not showing the full star,

Comment: When it load no star are showing, and i am not seeing no full stars in my table view

Comment: Can you please suggest some help. I am getting 5 blank stars. its not coming as per my json value ( Rating )