# How to get CFBundleURLSchemes of an app in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, url-scheme, fitbit

I have made a demo project App1 in which I added a button which will redirect me to the installed app suppose App2("**fitbit**") I have gone through many tutorials and basically got the idea how to do this through the 2nd answer ["This app is not allowed to query for scheme cydia" IOS9 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722638/this-app-is-not-allowed-to-query-for-scheme-cydia-ios9-error) .but got stucked at a point where I need to mention URL Scheme of App2("**fitbit**") at LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in App1.

[image]

So basically the question is how to get the URL Schemes of the apps like ***fitbit***.

[image]

and here are my codes

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/in/app/fitbit/id462638897?mt=8")
@IBAction func redirectOnclick(_ sender: Any) {
        let urlFitBt  = NSURL(string: "fitbit://")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlFitBt! as URL)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(urlFitBt! as URL)
        }
        else
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this

swift 2.2

```
        let fitbit = "fitbit://"    //this is fitbit URLSCHEME
        let fitbiturl = NSURL(string: fitbit)

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fitbiturl!)
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fitbiturl!)

        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/fitbit/id462638897?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2")!)
        }
```

and add this line into info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fitbit</string>
    </array>
```