# Opening Instagram App in Swift, with a custom URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api, url-scheme

There's a button in my project that opens Instagram when tapped. The problem is I need this button to open Instagram, and if the user was *in the middle of* editing a photo, it takes them right back to the photo editing tab.

With my code below, the button takes the user to Instagram's main feed. If they were in the middle of editing a photo, it clears that out.

Is there a custom URL scheme that will open Instagram, without 'erasing' any progress the user was currently working on? EG - writing their image description, or editing their image with filters.

// Instagram button pressed:

```
let urlStr: String = "instagram://app"
let url = URL(string: urlStr)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
    print("can open")
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
}
```

I also tried `"instagram://"` and `"instagram://camera"` - but the problem persists of clearing out the screen that the user was currently working on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934746/how-to-get-cfbundleurlschemes-of-an-app-in-ios-swift/41949886#41949886

Comment: That solution is pretty much exactly what I'm doing. The issue is if the user was in the middle of editing something within Instagram, then presses home button, then presses the "Open Instagram" button using the code I posted above, it clears out everything the user was doing in Instagram, and just brings them to the main feed. I need to avoid that.

Comment: Hey Joe! Having the same problem in 2020; I was wondering if you have any solution by now :)

Answer (score 4):

According to Instagram iPhone Hooks documentation, there is no URL scheme for editing a photo.

source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/

Comment: Is there any way to open Instagram up, without it defaulting to one of the URL schemes? So essentially, if Instagram is already open in the background, it just brings it back to the foreground, without clearing out what the user was doing.

Comment: As far as I know, URL scheme is the only way to open the Instagram app from other apps. Read here for inter-app communication in iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html