# Open app via URL scheme without directing to specific page?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I bring an app (say, Instagram) to the foreground without affecting its current page/state?

I can open Instagram from my app using its URL scheme: `instagram://app`

For example: `UIApplication.shared.open("instagram://app")` on button click.

However, when I click this button, it always redirects to the *Instagram home page*, even if I previously had Instagram open to a different page (my profile, some reel, etc.) How do I direct the user back to Instagram to continue where they left off?

This question was asked ~5 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229015/opening-instagram-app-in-swift-with-a-custom-url-scheme), but was never resolved. **I know this kind of redirect is possible (since it's basically what [one sec](https://one-sec.app/) does), but I'm stumped as to how it accomplishes that.**

Comment: I think you can't, but of course everything is possible, but it'll be so much more complicated than this.

Comment: Is your question specific to the Instagram app, are you asking a more general question about your own app, or are you asking about other apps in general?

Comment: @HangarRash I want to create a button in my app that opens Instagram in its current state. The [one sec](https://one-sec.app/) app seems to do exactly this (it doesn’t redirect to the home page every time I tap “Continue to Instagram”)

Comment: I've never used Instagram. Do they document their custom URL scheme anywhere? What about the URL `instagram://` ?

Comment: using `instagram://` instead of `instagram://app` yields the same result

Comment: Why did you undo the changes I made to your question? Your question is specifically asking about opening Instagram. It's not a general question about opening any app.